# Stuck with 'contenteditable'

Tags: javascript, html, web, richtextbox, contenteditable

I am developing one Rich Text Box using JavaScript.By reading some excellent reference in Mozilla I have developed content editable div to make text Bold , Italic, Underline and some more fundamental effects. But When I apply the effect to my whole text and after that I am not able to put cursor(carat) out side of the tag. Like when I type something my Div (contenteditable = "true") becomes editable. And I type "ABC". Then I select "ABC" and I press the Bold Button. And I got Bold text but after that I am not able to type in my div without "BOLD" tag. Can some one give me the solution. By Observing following code and output I hope I will clear my question. Thanking you in advance.

```
$(function(){           
    $("#btn_bold").click(function () {
    document.execCommand("bold",true,"");
  });
});
```

HTML Code.

```
  <div class="container">
      <div id="myEditTextBox" contenteditable="true">
      </div>
       <button id="btn_bold" type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Bold" >B</button>
```

So When I type ABC and select it I got "**ABC**" which is pretty fine. Now when I click on div to focus it and type it is appending to "`<b> </b>`" not in "`<div>`" so after "**ABC**" if I write D the out put is "**ABCD**" but I want "**ABC**D". Thanking you.

Answer (score 1):

You can either click the button again or add onBlur to toggle bold again

EDIT:

I was thinking about something like this:

```
$(function() {

    var itsBold = false;

    var toggleBold = function() {
        document.execCommand("bold", true, "");
        itsBold = !itsBold;
    };

    var onBlur = function() {
        if(itsBold) toggleBold();
    };

    $("#btn_bold").click(toggleBold);
    $("#myEditTextBox").blur(onBlur);

});
```

Comment: But my friend I am not able to do it. Can you give me code example?